# Saving files/settings on a live usb

Tags: linux, usb, fedora

I have installed Fedora onto a usb stick and no matter what I do I cannot save files or even my settings onto the os. I have tried re-installing fedora but it was the same again. When I start up the os it boots as a brand new system and my files from the previous session are gone. I am just wondering is it possible to shut down my pc and still have my files when I login again.

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It may be more appropriate on the related sites http://unix.stackexchange.com (Unix & Linux) OR http://superuser.com . Consider using the flag link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Thanks and Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

Live OS are stored in ramdisk, which means that they allocates an area of the main memory and then mounts it as a drive in the file system. On reboot all informations are lost.
The obvious conclusion is that **you can't save files and settings** on the live USB image.

**But** you should be able to reserve a partition on the USB to store your settings/files. This is called **persistency mode** (see this [article](https://www.maketecheasier.com/persistent-live-usb-vs-full-install-usb/) for example).

On fedora to enable data persistance, just follow the instruction provided [here](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_and_use_Live_USB#Data_persistence).

Maybe what you want is not a live USB but a full install on USB.

Comment: Note that the persistent mode is pretty flaky and will cause problems over time. If you need to run from a USB stick long term, I suggest _installing_ to it, rather than running as live media.